# How to correctly parse nested json with Python where several keys are equal

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, normalization, flatten

I have a problem with `flatten` / `json_normalize` functions. There's a nested json with 6 "receipts" in it, but flattening this json gives me only 1 row with 1 receipt, which is also last, I need all 6 in my pandas dataframe.

```json
[
  {
    "_index": "packets-2020-02-03",
    "_type": "receipts_file",
    "_score": null,
    "_source": {
      "layers": {
        "frame": {
          "frame.encap_type": "25",
          "frame.time": "Feb  3, 2019 00:17:14.004011000 MSK",
          "frame.offset_shift": "0.000000000",
          "frame.time_epoch": "2575325034.004011000",
          "frame.time_delta": "0.002843000",
          "frame.time_delta_displayed": "0.002843000",
          "frame.time_relative": "0.002852000",
          "frame.number": "4",
          "frame.len": "1294",
          "frame.cap_len": "1294",
          "frame.marked": "0",
          "frame.ignored": "0",
          "frame.protocols": "several"
        },
        "receipts": {
          "receipts.command_length": "238",
          "receipts.command_id": "0x00000005",
          "receipts.sequence_number": "47207",
          "receipts.data_coding": "0x00000000",
          "receipts.data_coding_tree": {
            "receipts.rps": "0x00000000",
            "Receipt Type 1 Data Coding": {
              "receipts.rps.rc_coding_group": "0x00000000",
              "receipts.rps.text_compression": "0",
              "receipts.rps.class_present": "0",
              "receipts.rps.charset": "0x00000000"
            },
            "Receipt Type 2 Data Coding": {
              "receipts.rps.rpk._coding_group": "0x00000000",
              "receipts.rps.rpk._language": "0x00000000"
            }
          },
          "receipts.rc_default_receipt_id": "0",
          "receipts.rc_length": "117",
          "receipts.receipt": "29831",
          "receipts.opt_params": {
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003002",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "47912"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003001",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "98982"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003004",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "1",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "00"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003000",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "4",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "23080"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003003",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "29849"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x0000001e",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "9",
              "receipts.receipted_receipt_id": "949BB6DE"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00000427",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "1",
              "receipts.receipt_state": "2"
            }
          }
        },
        "receipts": {
          "receipts.command_length": "241",
          "receipts.command_id": "0x00000005",
          "receipts.sequence_number": "47208",
          "receipts.data_coding": "0x00000000",
          "receipts.data_coding_tree": {
            "receipts.rps": "0x00000000",
            "Receipt Type 1 Data Coding": {
              "receipts.rps.rc_coding_group": "0x00000000",
              "receipts.rps.text_compression": "0",
              "receipts.rps.class_present": "0",
              "receipts.rps.charset": "0x00000000"
            },
            "Receipt Type 2 Data Coding": {
              "receipts.rps.rpk._coding_group": "0x00000000",
              "receipts.rps.rpk._language": "0x00000000"
            }
          },
          "receipts.rc_default_receipt_id": "0",
          "receipts.rc_length": "117",
          "receipts.receipt": "98341",
          "receipts.opt_params": {
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003002",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "38220"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003001",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "93813"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003004",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "1",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "00"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003000",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "4",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "98381"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003003",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "77371"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x0000001e",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "9",
              "receipts.receipted_receipt_id": "6DED391C"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00000427",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "1",
              "receipts.receipt_state": "2"
            }
          }
        },
        "receipts": {
          "receipts.command_length": "238",
          "receipts.command_id": "0x00000005",
          "receipts.sequence_number": "47209",
          "receipts.data_coding": "0x00000000",
          "receipts.data_coding_tree": {
            "receipts.rps": "0x00000000",
            "Receipt Type 1 Data Coding": {
              "receipts.rps.rc_coding_group": "0x00000000",
              "receipts.rps.text_compression": "0",
              "receipts.rps.class_present": "0",
              "receipts.rps.charset": "0x00000000"
            },
            "Receipt Type 2 Data Coding": {
              "receipts.rps.rpk._coding_group": "0x00000000",
              "receipts.rps.rpk._language": "0x00000000"
            }
          },
          "receipts.rc_default_receipt_id": "0",
          "receipts.rc_length": "117",
          "receipts.opt_params": {
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003002",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "38717"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003001",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "37788"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003004",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "1",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "74818"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003000",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "4",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "77812"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003003",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "39999"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x0000001e",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "9",
              "receipts.receipted_receipt_id": "273A872F"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00000427",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "1",
              "receipts.receipt_state": "2"
            }
          }
        },
        "receipts": {
          "receipts.command_length": "242",
          "receipts.command_id": "0x00000005",
          "receipts.sequence_number": "47210",
          "receipts.data_coding": "0x00000000",
          "receipts.data_coding_tree": {
            "receipts.rps": "0x00000000",
            "Receipt Type 1 Data Coding": {
              "receipts.rps.rc_coding_group": "0x00000000",
              "receipts.rps.text_compression": "0",
              "receipts.rps.class_present": "0",
              "receipts.rps.charset": "0x00000000"
            },
            "Receipt Type 2 Data Coding": {
              "receipts.rps.rpk._coding_group": "0x00000000",
              "receipts.rps.rpk._language": "0x00000000"
            }
          },
          "receipts.rc_default_receipt_id": "0",
          "receipts.rc_length": "118",
          "receipts.receipt": "69322",
          "receipts.opt_params": {
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003002",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "83881"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003001",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "73188"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003004",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "1",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "00"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003000",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "4",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "78881"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003003",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "74388"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x0000001e",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "9",
              "receipts.receipted_receipt_id": "949C60DF"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00000427",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "1",
              "receipts.receipt_state": "2"
            }
          }
        },
        "receipts": {
          "receipts.command_length": "238",
          "receipts.command_id": "0x00000005",
          "receipts.sequence_number": "47211",
          "receipts.data_coding": "0x00000000",
          "receipts.data_coding_tree": {
            "receipts.rps": "0x00000000",
            "Receipt Type 1 Data Coding": {
              "receipts.rps.rc_coding_group": "0x00000000",
              "receipts.rps.text_compression": "0",
              "receipts.rps.class_present": "0",
              "receipts.rps.charset": "0x00000000"
            },
            "Receipt Type 2 Data Coding": {
              "receipts.rps.rpk._coding_group": "0x00000000",
              "receipts.rps.rpk._language": "0x00000000"
            }
          },
          "receipts.rc_default_receipt_id": "0",
          "receipts.rc_length": "117",
          "receipts.receipt": "12281",
          "receipts.opt_params": {
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003002",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "12727"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003001",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "18828"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003004",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "1",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "00"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003000",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "4",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "38218"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003003",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "47718"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x0000001e",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "9",
              "receipts.receipted_receipt_id": "949BD094"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00000427",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "1",
              "receipts.receipt_state": "2"
            }
          }
        },
        "receipts": {
          "receipts.command_length": "25",
          "receipts.command_id": "0x80000004",
          "receipts.command_status": "0x00000000",
          "receipts.sequence_number": "35572",
          "receipts.receipt_id": "949C23B8"
        }
      }
    }
  }
]
```

I tried to use this code:

```python
import json
import pandas as pd
from flatten_json import flatten

i_file_name = 'example.json'

with open(i_file_name) as fd:
     json_data = json.load(fd)
json_data = (flatten(d, '.') for d in json_data)

df = pd.DataFrame(json_data)

df.head()
```

and

```python
import pandas as pd

i_file_name = 'example.json'

df = pd.read_json(i_file_name)
df = pd.json_normalize(df['_source'])

df.head()
```

They give me the same result: just 1 row, not 6. I tried to set `record_path` and `meta` with `json_normalize` but I couldn't figure out how to do that. I'm kinda new to json parsing and I couldn't find similar issues here. I know that I need to set the right keys, but I don't know how

EDIT:

Unfortanutely, StackOverflow has a limited support of tables in questions, so I'll just try to explain my expected output.

Right now I'm getting just one row with those columns:

- _index
- _type
- _score
- _source.layers.frame.*
- _source.source.receipts.*

where * means that there are several columns under the same level

receipts.* contain just 5 columns:

- command_length
- command_id
- command_status
- sequence_number
- receipt_id

and that 1 row that I'm getting contains values for these columns from the last "receipts"-level records:

```json
 "receipts": {
          "receipts.command_length": "25",
          "receipts.command_id": "0x80000004",
          "receipts.command_status": "0x00000000",
          "receipts.sequence_number": "35572",
          "receipts.receipt_id": "949C23B8"
}
```

but there are also other "receipts"-level records, such as:

```json
"receipts": {
          "receipts.command_length": "238",
          "receipts.command_id": "0x00000005",
          "receipts.sequence_number": "47207",
          "receipts.data_coding": "0x00000000",
          "receipts.data_coding_tree": {
            "receipts.rps": "0x00000000",
            "Receipt Type 1 Data Coding": {
              "receipts.rps.rc_coding_group": "0x00000000",
              "receipts.rps.text_compression": "0",
              "receipts.rps.class_present": "0",
              "receipts.rps.charset": "0x00000000"
            },
            "Receipt Type 2 Data Coding": {
              "receipts.rps.rpk._coding_group": "0x00000000",
              "receipts.rps.rpk._language": "0x00000000"
            }
          },
          "receipts.rc_default_receipt_id": "0",
          "receipts.rc_length": "117",
          "receipts.receipt": "29831",
          "receipts.opt_params": {
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003002",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "47912"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003001",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "98982"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003004",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "1",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "00"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003000",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "4",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "23080"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00003003",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "10",
              "receipts.vendor_op": "29849"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x0000001e",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "9",
              "receipts.receipted_receipt_id": "949BB6DE"
            },
            "receipts.opt_param": {
              "receipts.opt_param_tag": "0x00000427",
              "receipts.opt_param_len": "1",
              "receipts.receipt_state": "2"
            }
          }
        },
```

that I want to see also as rows in pandas dataframe. So the current row, that I'm getting, should be the 6th in it.

I kind of understood that my json is somehow broken since it has 6 different keys with the same name (receipts), but maybe I can parse it differently so that I can import it to Pandas correctly

Comment: the keys you are interested in : receipts.opt_param?  can u list out the 6 keys? you can also add an example dataframe of ur expected output

Comment: thanks! I edited my question to give more insides on the expected output. I meant "receipts"-level records, there are 6 of them in my example

Comment: There is something going on that I cant quite understand. Checking the data, without pandas, just ur regular python, and you discover that the other keys (receipt type 2 data coding, ...) do not show up.

Comment: I don't think that there are any problems with python/pandas, it's definitely in json since there are non-unique keys. It just took me by surprise. I still need to parse it tough, unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've realized that I didn't answer my question but actually managed to solve it. I apologize for the following code, but if you want to solve a problem like that, it might help. I've decided that I'd rather show the world my silly code than to leave it without any solution.

Firstly, I did as I mentioned in my question:

```
import pandas as pd

i_file_name = 'example.json'

df = pd.read_json(i_file_name)
df = pd.json_normalize(df['_source'])
```

then I converted it to json and imported it again to Pandas:

```
df_json = df.to_json(orient='records')

df = pd.read_json(df_json, orient='columns')
```

then I melted some of the layers:

```
df_melt = pd.melt(df, id_vars=['layers.frame.frame.time',
                          'layers.frame.frame.number'
                       value_vars=['layers.receipts'])
```

after that, I created a new DataFrame with those melted values and saved index to later join 2 dataframes.

```
df_melt2 = pd.DataFrame(df_melt['value'].values.tolist(), index=df_melt)
```

then I joined 2 dataframes together and dropped no longer needed columns

```
df_melt_full = pd.concat([df_melt, df_melt2], axis=1)
df_melt_full = df_melt_full.drop(['value', 'variable'], axis=1)
```

after that, I melted it again (yeah, that's my code from February and I'm ashamed of it)

```
df_melt_full_melt = pd.melt(df_melt_full, 
                            id_vars=['layers.frame.frame.time',
                                     'layers.frame.frame.number']
                           )
```

and imported it again

```
df_normalized = pd.json_normalize(df_melt_full_melt['value'])
```

then, finally, I joined 2 dataframes together and got my problem solved

```
df_final = pd.concat([df_melt, df_normalized], axis=1)
```